# Why is my linksys spa not recognizing hangup?

Tags: debian, asterisk, linksys, phone

I have a Linksys SPA which is connected to my one asterisk server. When I receive an incoming call, the PSTN line of the Linksys is forwarding the call to my server. However, when it's going to the voicemail part because nobody answered, it's going wrong. The Linksys only recognize the hangup if I press the pound key at the end, but when I hang up, the line keeps open. I already tried CPC detection on the Linksys but I'm not getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it. The problem was that the disconnect tone has to be set to my providers default in my case Ziggo. I found the information on `https://vxlabs.com/tag/ziggo/`.
Maybe it can help others.